# Syntax error when running my program (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

This is my script:

```
def info():
  print '\n'.join(commands)
```

The exception highlights the print '\n' part but I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: When asking this type of question, you should definitely include the traceback.

Comment: What error exactly are you getting? Can you add the error message?

Comment: @BalthazarRouberol Sorry, this is my first post but thanks for the advice.

Comment: You can edit your question and include the trace back.

Comment: I got the answer I need now but I'll remember than the next time I ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Python 3.x, [`print`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) should be function form.

```
def info():
    print('\n'.join(commands))
```

BTW, `commands` is not passed as parameter. Then it refers to global varaible `commands`.

Comment: @Hyperboreus, Ah.. I forgot free variable.